# Trigger HealthCheck by code in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, health-check, grpc-dotnet

I am working with microservice (multiple services) and want to have HealthCheck service which I can call and get health of all the running service. I wan't to trigger healthcheck for each of the service. The idea is to get health of each service via GRPC.

One of my service has :

'''
services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck("Ping", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Ping is OK!"), tags: new[] { "ping_tag" }).AddDbContextCheck(name: "My DB");
'''

How can I run health check through code when my GRPC endpoint is called in this service and get result.

Comment: gRPC has a health check interface that you can implement on all your services.  You would still need something to call it though.  https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear (first time on stackoverflow). I am not trying to do a healthcheck of gRPC but I am trying to use gRPC to do a healthcheck of other services as well (like database).
I am able to connect gRPC all together (send and receive is working fine) but I want to know the best way to query the default "healthcheck" pipleline (Which we get from app.UseHealthChecks("/health");).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `services.AddHealthChecks()` is invoked, an instance of `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckService` is added to the container. You can access this instance using dependency injection and call `CheckHealthAsync` to generate a health report which will use the registered health checks.

In my project I needed to execute the health check, when a MassTransit event is received:

```
public class HealthCheckQueryEventConsumer : IConsumer<IHealthCheckQueryEvent>
{
    private readonly HealthCheckService myHealthCheckService;   
    public HealthCheckQueryEventConsumer(HealthCheckService healthCheckService)
    {
        myHealthCheckService = healthCheckService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IHealthCheckQueryEvent> context)
    {
        HealthReport report = await myHealthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();
        string response = JsonSerializer.Serialize(report);
        // Send response
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for.